# Executing the content of the shell file in php

Tags: php, linux, shell

Firstly, We have a shell script say `ifelsesh.sh` having the following code

```
a=20 
b=20 

if [ $a == $b ] 
then 

    echo "a is equal to b"
else

    echo "a is not equal to b"
fi
```

Now, we want to execute this file by php say `execSh.php` as

```
       <?php
   // $contents = file_get_contents('ifelsesh.sh');
    try
    {
    exec('ifelsesh.sh',$output);
    echo $output;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e;
    }
```

when we run the file through the command line works fine

```
>php execSh.php
```

but when we run the `execSh.php` file through the browser nothing works,why and let us know the exact reason to sort it out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just execute the `.sh` script directly?

Comment: Also, from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) about `shell_exec()` - _"It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required."_

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in `php.ini` function `shell_exec`, `exec` are enabled.

You can use the `exec` to execute the `shell` script through PHP , make sure `exec` is enable on your machine

```
<?php
   exec(dirname(__FILE__) . '/ifelsesh.sh');
?>
```

Comment: Instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`, you can use `__DIR__`.

Comment: Thank you sir for reply, but not working and giving output as `array(0) { }`.

Comment: @NagarajuChimmani: if u changed .ini file then you must need to restart apache.